# How can the Rambam say there is no argument about sukkah size?

Tags: sukkah

The Rambam says in his introduction to the Mishneh that there is never any argument about things received by tradition, for example that a sukkah is 7 by 7:

> ושלא יהיה בחללה פחות משבעה טפחים אורך על שבעה טפחים רוחב

However the gemora (sukkah 7) has three opinions about the size of a sukkah (7 by 7 handbreadths, 6 by 6, or 4 amos by 4 amos), so how can the Rambam claim that?

Comment: I found a recent sefer on Otzar HaChochmah asks your question. He says the Pri Megadim (634 Eishel Avraham 1) says 7x7 is halacha lemoshe misinai, and the Beur Halacha asks on him that how could that be, when it's a dispute what the size is. The sefer says the Pri Megadim must be coming from your Rambam, but then we still have your question.

Comment: The Chavos Yair famously asked many such questions on that Rambam.